# Adding text to a UIWebView text box

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

How can I physically put some text from a UITextField into a form in a UIWebView in my iOS app? Maybe a javascript string could be called to input the text?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382817/load-image-logo-in-existing-html-input-field-uiwebview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Matt H suggested, you need to inject your javascript. So there are basically two parts to this problem. 1st you have your objective C.

```
    NSString *username = @"Fred";
    NSString *password = @"pAssw0rd"; 
    NSString *jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"updateWebForm('%@,%@');",username,password];    
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

Then you will have your javascript function, i put mine in a .js file, that my webview page is linked to.

```
updateWebForm(username,password)
{
 //here is where you will assign whatever html/javascript needed for your form.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, great stuff but I don't understand what I need to put in the updateWebForm javascript section :S

Comment: To update that, change username, password to your username.text, password.text. The javascript function would contain.. document.getElementById('usernamefield').value = username; document.getElementById('passwordfield').value = password;

Comment: Great, thanks! :D How do I link up the .js file in XCode now? :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me, the text boxes are still empty. Here's the code I am using: http://pastie.org/2731306 - what's wrong?

Comment: hmm...my javascript isn't amazing. But in the javascript you are saying username.text. And that might work, but i'm pretty sure you are just passing a string. It's not the object or anything. Maybe try just "username". in your java function.

Comment: Time to do a little caveman debugging. Try to follow it through with NSLogs in the objective C and console.logs in the javascript side. Try to see where you are getting to.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject Javascript into a UIWebView:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javascript goes here"];
```

Use that with $('#fieldid').val('fromuitextfield'); or with document.getElementById() or however you need to change the text field value property.

Comment: how can I put username.text and password.text instead of ID usernamefield and passwordfield? Could you please provide an example? :)